# Div on Div displaced

Tags: html, overlay

[image]

I'm trying to write a div on div and I'm stuck trying to get the title right on the line of the div. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Please share html and css you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in looking into `position` of en element.

For example, using the middle box as the 'middle' div, and a `displaced` div for this title;

```css
.outer {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 400px;
  width: 80%;
  border: 5px solid red;
  position: relative;
}
.middle {
  height: 200px;
  width: 80%;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  
  /*centering the blue div to middle of the red box*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.displaced {
  font-size: 30px;
  
  /*needed to put the green div up onto the line*/
  position: absolute;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="displaced">
      this will be on the line
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

For more information please read the [w3c documents](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/position) relating to this positioning.

**Further Reading**

- The [transform property](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/), which allows you to use this 'translate' the child element with relation to the parent who has a position defined (such as relative, or in this case, 'middle' div's absolute position)

Comment: might be beneficial to explain to him what `translate` does, since he doesn't understand `position` (maybe). Also it'd be a good idea to through a `background-color` on the `.displaced` so the title can actually be read (even though his example doesn't have that).

Comment: Is there a way to keep the title centered even if the width of the page is being changed(dragging around your browser width)?

Comment: @user2515606 I have updated my answer to include this, although I think you would benefit from reading the link I've posted on the `transform` property.